# how to convert date & time format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

My Script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="date_time" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var date_time = $('#date_time').val();
        alert(date_time); // return 2015-08-18 11:58:21
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's alert in the format `2015-08-18 11:58:21`, but i want to convert my date and time format, using javascript, to `18 August 2015, 11:58 AM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<script>
var given_date = '2015-11-18 11:58:21';
var date_arr = given_date.split(" "); 
var ymd = date_arr[0];
ymd = ymd.split('-');

var y = ymd[0];
var m = ymd[1];
var d = ymd[2];

var his = date_arr[1];
his = his.split(':');

var h = his[0];
var i = his[1];
var s = his[2];

var ampm = (h >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM";
var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June','July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

$('#date').html(d + ' ' + months[m-1] + ' ' + y + '   ' + h + ':' + i + ' ' +  ampm);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are using jQuery, so you can use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) plugin to convert date and time as you needed. It's relay ease to use.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="date_time" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var date_time = $('#date_time').val();
        date_time = moment(date_time, "DD MMMM YYYY, hh:mm A");
        alert(date_time); // return 18 August 2015, 11:58 AM
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "It's really ease to use". How about showing him some example code of how to use the "moment.js" plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Change your date format to

```
<?php
 echo date("F j, Y, g:i a"); ?>
```

> It's return // August 18, 2015, 3:37 pm

Read [date format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: First Thanks for giving answer but i want this conversion in javascript not in php can you help me ??

Comment: If date is coming form database you can easily converted into your data format using php . Why you use JavaScript fot it??